# How could this Java method be improved?

Tags: java, performance

I am parsing XML files and I have several methods similar to:

```
public static Integer getInteger(Object integer) {
  if (integer == null) {
     return 0;
  }

  try {
     return Integer.parseInt(integer.toString(), 10);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

So basically, you pass an object in with the assumption of converting it to an Integer (I also have versions for Float, etc).

This seems to work well but being a Java newbie, I was wondering how you would improve it.  I am especially interesting in the boxing/unboxing aspect (at least, from a C# developer's perspective).

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry, I wasn't clear to what goes into the method.  Yes, it's for an XML file now so it's always a string. But the string could be empty or maybe even null.  I guess I wanted to always return a 0 if there was an error of any kind.

Comment: This is probably better off in codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What exactly do you pass to the function? Is it really absolutely any kind of object? It could be optimized/implemented differently, if only specific objects are passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say whether `integer` is an instance of `Integer` or not. If it is you can just cast it:

```
Integer i = (Integer) integer;
```

having checked for `null` and `instanceof` first.

If it is not an instance of Integer then what you're doing seems reasonable, although you only need to catch a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Thanks all for the tips.  I gave a +1 for all who pointed out I should be using NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't generally catch `Exception`. Catching `NumberFormatException` would be more appropriate here.

Any reason for converting to `Integer` instead of `int`? Why not let the caller perform the boxing conversion *if* they need it?

Comment: Well, I wanted a clean method for returning an integer.  I would say that 100% of the time, the input will be either a `number of sorts(1.2, 1, -333.34523452435243)` a `string ("1.2")` or `null`.  I'm still new to Java so I'm not sure the pros/cons of `Integer` vs `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use instanceof operator, then make safe casting (so if Object integer is instanceof Integer, cast it).

Then you don't have to catch Exception (which in this case is unchecked NumberFormatException)

```
    public static Integer getInteger(Object integer) {
      if (integer == null) {
         return 0;
      }
      if (integer instanceof Integer) {
         return (Integer)integer;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

**EDIT**

If data is coming from XML, then it will of course never be Integer :) Then parsing from String is required still, so see other answers.

Comment: Ahhh, I guess, he gets the "integers" from an xml document and so I guess, the real type is `String` rather then `Integer`.

Comment: This wouldn't cover non-`Integer` objects which the original does, such as `String`s.

Comment: Ah, so it will never be instance of Integer :)) Ok I'll edit answer

Answer (score 1):

As Jon hinted, returning `int` (the primitive data type) instead of `Integer` (the wrapper class) would probably be better (assuming you never want to return `null`).

Also, adding this code could be a shortcut, when the input is often an `Integer` object or other [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#Number%28%29) subclass (I'm calling the input `input` because it's too confusing otherwise):

```
if (input instanceof Number) {
  return ((Number) integer).intValue();
}
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that the difference between `Integer` and `int` is allowing nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Integer` makes sense if you want to signal, that a value is empty. You're testing that already but you shouldn't return `0`, unless you have a very clear and somewhat special requirement to do so. *No value* is not equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can add more special cases besides `null`, like check for empty string:

```
public static Integer getInteger(Object integer) {
    if (integer == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        String s = integer.toString();
        if (s.isEmpty())
             return 0;
        return Integer.parseInt(s, 10);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

On the other side, you can cut all special cases, and go with only:

```
public static Integer getInteger(Object integer) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(integer.toString(), 10);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the end, performance gains (or losses) depends on what portion of your input data is `null`, empty, unparsable integers, or "normal" integer strings.